# Erro de roteamento em Rails - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rotas

Galera, criei uma aplicação em rails e gerei alguns models, controllers etc. Da seguinte forma:

```
rails g scaffold nivelIntermediario/Historia descricao:string
```

Meu arquivo de rotas ficou assim:

```
namespace :nivel_intermediario do
   resources :historias
end
```

E o meu controlador assim:

```
class NivelIntermediario::HistoriaController < ApplicationController
```

Ai toda vez que tendo acessar para criar uma nova história aparece esse erro:

```
uninitialized constant NivelIntermediario::CartasController
```

Segue as rotas:

```
nivel_intermediario_historias GET    /nivel_intermediario/historias(.:format)          nivel_intermediario/historias#index
                                  POST   /nivel_intermediario/historias(.:format)          nivel_intermediario/historias#create
 new_nivel_intermediario_historia GET    /nivel_intermediario/historias/new(.:format)      nivel_intermediario/historias#new
edit_nivel_intermediario_historia GET    /nivel_intermediario/historias/:id/edit(.:format) nivel_intermediario/historias#edit
     nivel_intermediario_historia GET    /nivel_intermediario/historias/:id(.:format)      nivel_intermediario/historias#show
                                  PATCH  /nivel_intermediario/historias/:id(.:format)      nivel_intermediario/historias#update
                                  PUT    /nivel_intermediario/historias/:id(.:format)      nivel_intermediario/historias#update
                                  DELETE /nivel_intermediario/historias/:id(.:format)      nivel_intermediario/historias#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa, dentro da controllers você deve ter uma pasta nivel_intermediario e dentro dela o arquivo historias_controller.rb.

Pode enviar um print da sua pasta controllers?

Comment: Me parece que sua resposta esta mais para um comentário, você poderia melhorar a sua resposta afim de solucionar o problema citado ?